# Mysql regexp match same substring in <year>, <year_0>, <year_1> tags

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

**Question**: Is it possible to have regexp match `>*2014*</year` substring so that only the nearest `>` char is a start of match. Another say is use regexp to match `>...XXXX...</year` substring but do not allow `<` char in a substring match.

Mysql regexp query to select year=2014 records, but this overflows start-end tag `>*2014*</year` and returns extra rows. I believe it starts matching from earlier `<start>2014-MM-DD</start>` tag.

```
Select * From table1 Where args REGEXP '>.*(2014).*<\/year'
```

Reason I don't use `'<year>.*(2014).*<\/year>'` is one or more year, year_0, year_1 tags and so on num of array tags is unlimited. I need to *select any row where year(contains)2014 no matter of which available year tag value is*.

Simplified example args column values, each line is a separate table row. Tag value is not just `year (equals) 2014` but `any year (contains) 2014` formula.

```
<title>Record 1</title><start>2014-01-31</start><year>text 2013 text</year><end>2014-02-17</end>
<title>Record 2</title><start>2014-01-03</start><year>any 2014 text</year><end>2014-01-26</end>
<title>Record 3</title><start>2014-03-07</start><year>aa 2015 bb</year><end>2014-03-12</end>
<title>Record 4m</title><start>2014-02-22</start><year>2014</year><year_0>like 2015 this</year_0><end>2014-03-01</end>
<title>Record 5m</title><start>2015-02-23</start><year>bb 2012 cc</year><year_0>2014 dd</year_0><year_1>2014</year_1><end>2015-03-02</end>
<title>Record 6m</title><start>2014-02-22</start><year>2013</year><year_0>like 2015 this</year_0><end>2014-03-01</end>
<title>Record 7m</title><year>2013</year><start>2014-02-22</start><year_0>like 2015 this</year_0><end>2014-03-01</end>
```

Here is [regex101.com online example](https://regex101.com/r/vU9zS2/2) to show an overflow problem, I need to match *year,year_0,year_1* so on tags not just `<year>` tag. This should not match a record because year has 2013,2015 substrings.

**Edit** Here is also [SqlFiddle online example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/313ad/1) to show an overflow problem *any_year=2014* match incorrect rows, I need to match year,year_0,year_1,... array values only. Row 7m should not be listed.

**Edit2** Best answer I think so far is `Where args REGEXP '<year[>_].*2014.*<\/year[>_]'` to look for array of year values in a single regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to escape slash with backslash `\/`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bbb0/8

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE args REGEXP '<year>.*2014.*<\/year>'
```

**UPDATE**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bbb0/9

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE args REGEXP '<year.*>.*2014.*<\/year.*>'
```

Comment: Alex: I added online regexp link to describe an overflow problem. I cannot just match <year> tag but all of them, it is like an array of values.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You have 5 records in sample provided and you want to get just 2 of them what my query exactly does. Do you want another record to be returned as well? add it to the sample set I will try to modify the query.

Comment: Sure, added 6th line and also sqlfiddle link at the end of my question. Last 6m row is year=2013,2015 values but 2014 query matches everything because of previous <start>2014-* tag. I don't have just <year> tag but <year_N> array so to speak making this a challenge.

Comment: Magic spell, you did it. I guess using (parenthesis) does not harm, it pops a keyword better out in a query string.  <year.*>.*(2014).*<\/year.*>

Comment: Minor issue found but probably I can live with it, if args are in this order `<title>Record 6m</title><year>2013</year><start>2014-02-22</start><year_0>like 2015 this</year_0><end>2014-03-01</end>` then year=2014 query incorrectly is a match due to a tag overflow problem. I try to see if app could sort args before saving a db.